# How to troubleshoot a water cooling kit or system?

Tags: troubleshooting, overheating, water-cooling

I purchased and installed a ["Thermaltake Pacific RL120 Water Cooling Kit"](http://www.thermaltake.com/Cooler/Liquid_Cooler_/LCS_Kits/C_00002692/Pacific_RL120_Water_Cooling_Kit/design.htm) in my computer, and it worked perfectly fine for past 6 months. Just few days ago though, my computer overheated and turned itself off. I realized that there was air in the pipes that may have caused water to not pump properly and therefore the overheating the system.

I filled more liquid to get rid of air, and in the process found out that one of the pipe was loose. I drained the water loop and redid the entire loop (this time everything is perfectly fit). Now, when I turn on the power the water won't pump back up to the CPU. I left it running on only for few minutes but the water won't move at all.

Before I go around replacing parts, I wanted to know proper way to troubleshoot such problem. If you guys can give me some suggestions, that will be awesome! I haven't contacted Thermaltake, I believe either I am doing something wrong or the [Thermeltake Pacific PR15](http://www.thermaltake.com/Cooler/Liquid_Cooler_/Pump_Reservoir/C_00002694/Pacific_PR15/design.htm), because as I understand that is the pump and if that doesn't work, water won't pump up. I have images available, but cannot attach them yet (due to my rep).

Comment: does the pump actually run? Anything mechanical should have SOME vibrations.

Comment: I can't tell. I don't think so. I have tried different ports on my motherboard to power it, but none of them seem to work.